# How to extract child nodes with the same child name but different values in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, xml-parsing

Within the XML file, there are child nodes that have the same node name, but with different values as can be seen from the example.

I have already tried what I could find on the internet, but alas, nothing worked. Moreover, I am new to PowerShell, and I've seen that it's really powerful, but this is just difficult because of a particular child node as you can see in the example.

```bsh
chdir('\\folder')
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content "football.xml"
```

First try:

```bsh
foreach ($s in $XmlDocument.entities.entity.ext) {
    $attribs = $s.Attributes
    if ($attribs = 'Alias') {
        $s
    }
}
```

Not sure what I am doing up here, but I was trying to loop through the file to get the value for the child node 'Alias' within the `<ext>` child node.

Then I tried the following:

```bsh
$XmlDocument.SelectNodes("//entities/entity/ext") | ForEach Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        Name  = $s_.name
        Alias = $s_.alias
    }
}
```

But this also didn't work. I also tried to export everything to CSV:

```bsh
$XmlDocument.entities.ChildNodes |
    Export-Csv "footballers.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter:";" -Encoding:UTF8
```

Which works really well, but the output for the `<ext>` child nodes is an aggregated error message.

So the input would be like below. And as can be seen, the `<ext>` nodes are not equally distributed as well, which makes it even more difficult. Sometimes there are certain `<ext>` nodes in some entity and sometimes not.

```xml
<entities>
    <entity id="1" version="1928">
        <name>Ronaldo, Cristiano</name>
        <datebirth>02/05/1985</datebirth>
        <country>Portugal</country>
        <ext name="Alias">Ronnie</ext>
        <ext name="Height">187</ext>
        <ext name="Nationality">Portuguese</ext>
        <ext name="Club">Juventus</ext>
        <ext name="Previously">Real Madrid</ext>
        <ext name="Brand">CR7</ext>
    </entity>
    <entity id="24" version="1928">
        <name>Messi, Lionel</name>
        <datebirth>06/24/1987</datebirth>
        <country>Argentina</country>
        <ext name="Alias">La Pulga</ext>
        <ext name="Height">170</ext>
        <ext name="Nationality">Argentine</ext>
        <ext name="Club">FC Barcelona</ext>
    </entity>
</entities>
```

And then I would like to convert all of this into a CSV file with all information inside the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second attempt got you almost there, but the XPath expression you have is selecting all `<ext>` nodes. What you want is an expression that selects all `<entity>` nodes that contain a child node `<ext>` with an attribute `name` that has the value `Alias`.

```
//entities/entity[ext[@name='Alias']]
```

Then you can build your custom objects like this:

```
New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    Name  = $_.name
    Alias = $_.SelectSingleNode("./ext[@name='Alias']").'#text'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using XPath, this should work:

```
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content "football.xml"

$data = foreach ($entity in $XmlDocument.entities.entity) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Name' = $entity.name
        'Alias' = ($entity.ext | Where-Object { $_.name -eq 'Alias' }).InnerText   # or use .'#text'
    }
}

$data | Export-Csv -Path '<PATH AND FILENAME FOR THE EXPORTED CSV FILE' -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';' -Encoding UTF8
```

`$data` will contain an array of PSCustomObjects you can easily export to an CSV file.
When output to console, it will look like this:

> ```
> Name               Alias   
> ----               -----   
> Ronaldo, Cristiano Ronnie  
> Messi, Lionel      La Pulga
> ```

Comment: Thanks Theo, this will probably work but I cannot test it at the moment. And Ansgar's Ansar worked. Thanks for the alternative though!